Which search engines can do "${@}" (or other searches with symbols), but are not limited to raw source code (such as GitHub is)?
Have used all possible combinations of quotes/escape codes on Google, StartPage and DuckDuckGo without success.
Those search engines have regressed so much that now it is not possible to search for exact matches of alphanumerics (such as "2 4 6 4 2"), let alone code. Which search engines can still do exact matches?
Some results for questions such as "How do you search for symbols or source code" just have responses such as "How do you expect search engines to allow special operators such as '!' or '@' if you can search for those", without mention of parsers/interpreters which use escape codes (such as backslash '\') to do this). Is there some fundamental aspect of search engines which prevents backslash use? Or are there search engines which do this?

If none can (in general) do this, how about just that specific example ("${@}")? Natural languages searches such as "Which rule says that /bin/sh does not allow braces around at?" do not give results fit to use.

Do you want regex, or have you tried regex searches?

Found some search engines which support simple regular expressions (such as "" to glob), but not search engines which allow to search for symbols (such as the actual character "" in source code). Wish to search across the normal internet (which includes tutorials and documentation) for search code.
